# C# await delay not working

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to pause the program so it does not close. I have a code running in the main thread. Tried this way, but this code instantly skips and the program closes instead of waiting.

How can I make it wait for the WaitMy method to complete?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //any code here...
        Console.WriteLine("Discovery started");

        WaitMy();
    }

    private async static void WaitMy()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(30 * 1000);
        await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(30 * 1000));
    }
```

The application runs with .net 4.5.

Comment: Just use `Console.Read();`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is would awaiting WaitMy work in this situation?

Comment: Since `WaitMy` is `async void` it's basically fire and forget.  Meaning `Main` will continue.  And even if it where `async Task` you'd then have to block on it.

Comment: 1) `await Task.Delay(30 * 1000);` 2) `static async Task Main(...)` [[C# 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1)] 3) `async static Task WaitMy()`

Comment: Is there a reason why you can not simply start the application from main thread *(from `main`)*? Since this is a console application, there is only one thread *(or is it not a console application?)* and therefore there is no reason why you need to make this type of approach.

Comment: Why are you creating a thread to do a delay?  You would not hire a worker to perform the task of doing nothing for a year, so don't hire a thread to do the same. **The whole point of task.delay is that it does not consume another thread** and you are *defeating* that feature.  What led you to believe this was a sensible thing to do? I am interested to learn how people come to write bad code so that I can help prevent it in the future.

Comment: @EricLippert It seemed to me that this code was just a mcve that was there to highlight the fact that a console app can start a task to do some work for some time (and not just 'waiting'...) and needs to wait for it to complete. This scenario makes sense if the console app actually starts several tasks and it needs to wait for all of them to complete before exiting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method `WaitMy` can return a `Task` instance so you can have your main thread wait for it to be completed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //any code here...
    Console.WriteLine("Discovery started");

    var task = WaitMy();

    task.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("And done :)");
}

private static Task WaitMy()
{
    //await Task.Delay(30 * 1000);
    return Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(30 * 1000));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like it, it works. I'm thinking of choosing this as the answer, if not against it.

Comment: This program is a deadlock, when used in a non console application, which rely on Ui synchronization context, as you block the main thread, continuation cannot happen on same thread thus a deadlock, well documented behavior check [Don't Block Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)
It shall be Async call all the way from top to the bottom of the Chain

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Non-console application is not the scenario addressed here though :)

Comment: @Kzrystof even then, post introduction of `async Main`, this is a bad choice. It is very easy to use the `WaitMy` inside a library and use it from multiple callers, which can cause the deadlock, hang

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to following to make it work:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //any code here...
    Console.WriteLine("Discovery started");

    await WaitMy();
}
```

> How this works ?

1. You need C# 7.1 or later versions
2. Now Main method can be declared async and has return type as `Task` for introducing `await`
3. It will simply let the delay execute asynchronously, but will renter the main context for continuation, which will not exit

Another suggestion would be, you just need `await Task.Delay(30 * 1000)`, wrapping inside the `Task.Run` is not required here

Comment: Yes that should be simple as that's when `Main` entry point is made async, similar to MVC controllers

Comment: Unfortunately, only net 4.5

Comment: @jenokizm C# 7.1 can target .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You are using Task Programming Library. What happens here is that, in your `WaitMy` method, you are scheduling a task to be executed (`await Task.Run(...)`). The task is being executed *on a background thread*.
In the meanwhile, the Main method continues its execution after the call to the `WaitMy` method.
The Main method ends right after, so the foreground thread is terminated, and all the background threads associated to its process are terminated too.
If you just want to perform a delay, just use:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
```

in the Main method, instead of calling WaitMy.

Comment: Don't use sleep; that prevents the main thread from doing any work!

Comment: Isn't that what he exactly wants to do? He is just at the end of the program and he wants the program to wait before exiting. What is the gain in using TPL in this case?

Comment: Yes I know that it will slow down the main thread, but I do not need it.

Comment: I waited but the main thread worked. One of the answers above me approached.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the program to wait before terminating a simple answer would be to use

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you are curious why program terminates without waiting it is because you delegate waiting to ThreadPool by using `Task.Run` so waiting occurs on another thread an your application simply terminates before it can receive any result from ThreadPool

Comment: To the downvoter, please tell me what is wronveith the answer so I can learn

Comment: I am not the down-voter, but this is just a hack to prevent the main thread from exiting and will exit on key press. if you have to block, then Task.Wait is still a convincing choice, though still a bad option for async call